# How to create batch file, not working fine

Tags: batch-file

How to create batch file, not working fine.
Have look on below code. My below code is not working

```
@echo off
echo user pi> ftpcmd.dat
echo 8460192650>> ftpcmd.dat
echo ls>> ftpcmd.dat
set a=%cd%
for %%I in (.) do set "files/%%~nxI"
echo mkdir %location%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %cd%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd %%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 185.72.10.84
pause
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: What are you trying to get it to do? Perhaps you could be more specific than "not working."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget the location :

```
@echo off
echo user pi> ftpcmd.dat
echo 8460192650>> ftpcmd.dat
echo ls>> ftpcmd.dat
set a=%cd%
for %%I in (.) do set location="files/%%~nxI"
echo mkdir %location%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %cd%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd %location%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 116.72.10.84
pause
del ftpcmd.dat
```